# Which is the latest supported version of gmsh in fipy module?

Tags: python, version, fipy

It seems to me that FiPys support for Gmsh relies upon which version of FiPy is installed which sounds reasonable. Where can I find the information about which version of gmsh is still supported in which version of fipy so I won't have to figure out which commands work and which only raise errors.

Excerpt FiPy Doc:

```
FiPy works with arbitrary polygonal meshes generated by Gmsh. FiPy provides two wrappers classes (Gmsh2D and Gmsh3D) enabling Gmsh to be used directly from python. The classes can be instantiated with a set of Gmsh style commands (see examples.diffusion.circle). The classes can also be instantiated with the path to either a Gmsh geometry file (.geo) or a Gmsh mesh file (.msh) (see examples.diffusion.anisotropy).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FiPy can use Gmsh >= 2.0. 
Prior to FiPy 3.3, FiPy could not use Gmsh 4.x.